# Disabling all D3 animations (for testing)

Tags: animation, d3.js

I'm looking for a D3 equivalent to [`jQuery.fx.off = true`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/).

Say you are writing tests (with Mocha, QUnit, etc.) for an app that uses D3. The app has some D3 animations (with `.transition()`).

Animations are really bad for tests:

First, they are slow.

Second, because they are asynchronous, they can easily cause flickering tests. Ideally, you'd want to avoid any calls to `setTimeout` / `setInterval` / `requestAnimationFrame`.

Is there a way to disable all D3 animations, so that they instantly (and ideally, synchronously) jump to the end state? (Perhaps if there's not an option, we can hook into [timer.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/core/timer.js)?)

Comment: [`d3.timer.flush()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_timer_flush) may help.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to mocking out transitions is executing them synchronously directly to their final state.

With D3.js v4, use:

```
function flushAllD3Transitions() {
    var now = performance.now;
    performance.now = function() { return Infinity; };
    d3.timerFlush();
    performance.now = now;
 }
```

With D3.js v3 and previous, do:

```
function flushAllD3Transitions() {
    var now = Date.now;
    Date.now = function() { return Infinity; };
    d3.timer.flush();
    Date.now = now;
 }
```

See also [d3 issue 1789](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1789).

Comment: For `d3` version 4, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42540416/16363).

Answer (score 7):

I do not know of a native way to do it in d3. But you can easily modify the d3 selector API to skip animations by augmenting the d3 prototypes:

HTML code to be animated:

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="0" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Animation and D3-augmentation code:

```
function animate(color){
    d3.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("width", 0).attr("fill", "white")
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("width", 100).attr("fill", color)
}

function augment(){
    // add a duration function to the selection prototype
    d3.selection.prototype.duration   = function(){ return this }
    // hack the transition function of d3's select API
    d3.selection.prototype.transition = function(){ return this }
}

animate("red")
console.log("normal animation done")
setTimeout( function(){
        augment()
        console.log("d3 hacked!")
        animate("green")
        console.log("animation skipped")
}, 1200 )
```

**Attention!** This hack may not work as a complete solution for you. You may want to extend this solution with other `transition().*` functions that are not available on the `d3.selection.prototype` and that you use in your application.
You may also consider other forms of animation supported by d3. Maybe there is more than `<selection>.transition()` that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can mock d3.timer function:

```
var d3timer = d3.timer;

d3.timer = function(callback, delay, then) {
    d3timer(callback, 0, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could take is to use a fake timer in your testing suite, like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock), which works with Mocha or QUnit. Jasmine also has a mock timer [built in](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Clock). I'd think this a better approach because it means the code you're testing is closer to the running code (as opposed to sabotaging the transition functions).