# d3 transition in unit-testing

Tags: unit-testing, animation, timer, d3.js, jasmine

I have an chart built by `d3` and which appears with transitions and I need to test chart when all transitions have ended. I use `jasmine` for unit-testing. How to do it?
I find method `d3.timer.flush()`, but it skips only first frame, but I want to skip all animations and see an final result right now and make some assertions on it.

Comment: I think the best strategy is to wait until all transitions have finished and then check your assertions.

Comment: Yes, jasmine can create async tests with timeout. But every transition takes a time about a second. Then if I have at least 10 tests that total time will be more 10 seconds. I think about overriding `d3` duration function to set minimal duration in my test cases

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can execute transitions synchronously directly to their final state with one call to D3's timer flush if you mock out its timestamp determination during the flush like so:

An alternative to mocking out transitions is executing them synchronously directly to their final state.

With D3.js v4, do:

```
function flushAllD3Transitions() {
    var now = performance.now;
    performance.now = function() { return Infinity; };
    d3.timerFlush();
    performance.now = now;
 }
```

With D3.js v3 and previous, do:

```
function flushAllD3Transitions() {
    var now = Date.now;
    Date.now = function() { return Infinity; };
    d3.timer.flush();
    Date.now = now;
 }
```

Mocking the transition altogether (to avoid the calculation overhead) yielded mixed results for me, for example if your final state is created with an `attrTween`, it needs to be executed.

See also our discussion in [d3 issue 1789](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1789) and [SO 14443724](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443724/disabling-all-d3-animations-for-testing).

Comment: thanks! I wouldn't guess that date need to be replaced to fake.