# d3js unit testing removal of elements

Tags: d3.js, jasmine

I am using `jasmine` to unit test some interactions in a `d3.js` chart.  I have been using `d3.timerFlush()` to complete the executions of animations.  This works great for when entering new elements or updating attribute, and I am able to accurately test the new values.  However, I am having a hard time getting it to remove elements.

I have a method like this:

```
exit() {
    let arcs = svg.selectAll("path.arc");

    arcs.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d, i) { return vm._arcTween(this, d) })
        .remove();
}
```

And my test looks something like this:

```
it('it will remove all of the pie related elements from the DOM', () => {
        chartSvc.exit();
        d3.timerFlush();
        let elements = svg.querySelectorAll(/* selects my elements */);
        expect(elements.length).toEqual(0);
});
```

which fails.  If I debug the tests, I can see that the elements are not being removed.  However if I change the expect:

```
expect(pieChartSvc._arcTween).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

that passes, so I know that the method is being executed correctly and the timer flushed, but the elements aren't removed.

What am I doing wrong?

This issue: [Disabling all D3 animations (for testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443724/disabling-all-d3-animations-for-testing)
does not answer my question.  The *transition* is being executed and the elements have been changed to the state they are in before they are removed from the DOM, however they still appear on the DOM

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068497/d3-transition-in-unit-testing), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443724/disabling-all-d3-animations-for-testing), [this](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/1789) and [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9644751), you need to set `Date.now` before flushing.

Comment: I have tried that exactly as it is in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068497/d3-transition-in-unit-testing and it still does not work.  The animation is being executed and the elements are in their new location, but they are not removed from the DOM

Comment: Misunderstood, I thought you were having trouble making the transition run to completion; reverted my close.

Comment: Are the elements removed when `exit()` is called normally (i.e., not by the unit test)?

Comment: Yes, they are.  The shift to `performance.now` from `date.now` (detailed below) solved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, figured it out, `d3` version 3 used to use `date.now` to measure time.  Version 4 moved to [performance.now](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/src/timer.js#L10).

So, the correct code should be:

```
it('it will remove all of the pie related elements from the DOM', () => {
    chartSvc.exit();
    performance.now = function() { return Infinity; };
    d3.timerFlush();
    let elements = svg.querySelectorAll(/* selects my elements */);
    expect(elements.length).toEqual(0);
});
```

---

Here's some test code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg width="300" height="300">
      <g transform="translate(20,20)">
        <path class="arc" d="M0,0L100,0"></path>
        <path class="arc" d="M0,50L100,50"></path>
        <path class="arc" d="M0,100L100,100"></path>
        <path class="arc" d="M0,150L100,150"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('svg');
      
      let arcs = svg.selectAll("path.arc");
      
      arcs.transition()
        .duration(10000)
        .remove();
          
      performance.now = function() { return Infinity; };
      d3.timerFlush();

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```